# Beamer: always overlay first table on same frame

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays, block

A similar question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217628/beamer-always-overlay-first-item-on-same-frame), but now rather than overlaying list items I would like to be able to overlay `table` floats. While this does the trick for blocks:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{block}<only@+>{First block}
%stuff
\end{block}

\begin{block}<only@+>{Second block}
%more stuff
\end{block}

\end{frame}
```

it does not, unfortunately, for tables:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{table}[!h]<only@+>
    \begin{tabular}{} %column specs
    %first table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{} %some caption
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]<only@+>
    \begin{tabular}{} %column specs
    %second table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{} %some caption
\end{table}

\end{frame}
```

Output: both tables on same slide with gibberish (¡only@+¿) written above them.
What would be the correct syntax in this case? Cheers.

P.S. If there is also a better syntax for overlaying blocks than the one I came up with, I'm all ears! :) Ideally I'm looking for something like `\begin{framebody}[<only@+>]` so that everything (blocks, tables, `itemize` or `enumerate` environments) inside the frame inherit that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to achieve what was intended.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{overprint}
\onslide*<1>{
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{cc} %column specs
    f & f%first table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{1} %some caption
\end{table}
}
%
\onslide*<2>{
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{cc} %column specs
    c & c
    %second table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{2} %some caption
\end{table}
}
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}
%
\begin{block}<only@+>{First block}
b
\end{block}
%
\begin{block}<only@+>{Second block}
f
\end{block}
%
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: corrects my previous cut and paste error!